# How to insert data from one table to another?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two tables named

```
newlab(Department_Name,Total_PC,MAC,Lab_Code,PC_Name,Purchase_Order_No,Brand,Model_Name,Price,Processor,Ram,HDD,HDD_Type,OS)
```

and

```
maintenance(Department_Name,MAC,Lab_Code,PC_Name,Purchase_Order_No,Brand,Model_Name,Price,Processor,Ram,HDD,HDD_Type)
```

I want to insert data from newlab to maintenance.

My code is

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ` maintenance`(MAC,Lab_Code,PC_Name,Purchase_Order_No,Brand,Model,Price,Processor,Ram,HDD,HDD_Type)SELECT MAC,Lab_Code,PC_Name,Purchase_Order_No,Brand,Model_Name,Price,Processor,Ram,HDD,HDD_Type FROM `newlab` WHERE PC_Name='".$PC_Name."'";
$ress = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if(!$ress)
{
    echo "Not done";
}
```

But the problem is that it always Outputs - "Not done". I want to know why the query is not executed.

Comment: Please format code with the `{}` button.

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO ` maintenance`(MAC,Lab_Code,PC_Name,Purchase_Order_No,Brand,Model,Price,Processor,Ram,HDD,HDD_Type)SELECT (MAC,Lab_Code,PC_Name,Purchase_Order_No,Brand,Model_Name,Price,Processor,Ram,HDD,HDD_Type) FROM `newlab` WHERE PC_Name='".$PC_Name."'";

Comment: What happens when you execute the sql, exactly?

Comment: query is not executed and it always goes to else part where i have printed that "not done " to check weather query is executed or not but query is not executed and it doesnt make any changes to data base

Comment: and i tried the above query in sql it shows error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$sql = &quot;INSERT INTO ` maintenance`(MAC,Lab_Code,PC_Name,Purchase_Order_No,Brand,' at line 1

Comment: Your table name is most likely `maintenance` and not ` maintenance`. I would add a blank before the `SELECT` (in fact I would use a new line) escape the input. No I would rewrite it as a prepared statement and bind the input parameter.

Comment: Put some space between your tokens.  Table name followed immediately by `(`, or `)` followed immediately by `select`, is probably not going to work.

Comment: As @VMai said, it's most likely an issue with the input parameter.

Comment: Try this: `$ress = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con);` and tell us what the output is.

Comment: it shows some syntax error ';' not expected

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will probably create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @Ken You missed a parentheses: `$ress = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));`